# Change JFrame background color

Tags: java

Created a JFrame and tried to change the background but it does not work.
I have looked at so many solutions here and on the Internet and it doesnt work , What is wrong in my code

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Process");
       JLabel label = new JLabel("Please wait...");
       JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();
       pb.setIndeterminate(true);
       pb.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(248, 201, 171));

       frame.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 186, 152));
       frame.setSize(400, 200);
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 186, 152));

       GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

       c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10); // make spaces between components on screen
       c.gridx = 0;
       c.gridy = 0;
       c.gridwidth = 20;
       panel.add(label, c);
       c.gridx = 1;
       c.gridy = 1;
       c.gridwidth = 20;

       panel.add(pb, c);
       frame.add(panel);
       frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. "Doesnt work" isnt a working problem description. At least describe how the frame looks like (and how you expect it to look like). A (small) screenshot might be helpful here too.

Comment: panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 186, 152)) is the color for your background, you are using that and it's working fine on my IDE

Comment: This might solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269043/jpanel-taking-up-the-whole-jframe

Answer (score 0):

try `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 186, 152));`

Comment: This answer changes the background, the problem is the panel is taking up the ENTIRE frame, and thus you only see the color the panel is set to.

Answer (score 0):

don't work on the frame, work on the frame.getContentPane(). This is also where your sub panel and layout should be set. Besides, you use gridbag constraints but you never set a gridbag layout first. Meanwhile, you add to the frame and even if you did add to the content pane, you also didn't specify a content pane layout.

Answer (score 0):

After doing changes in my code I found that the problem is caused by the GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints(); 
so i changed this by using   panel.setLayout(null); then used setBounds to adjust the position of the components  label.setBounds(100, 30, 250, 10);
and everything os ok